# How can't I occur an Error when using NSURLConnection?

Tags: cocoa, release, nsurlconnection, dealloc

a scenario is below.

I made two Controllers, A tableViewController, B viewController and C ScrollView.
A tableViewController has cell that is entering to B viewController.
and B viewController has C scrollView that is B's front View.

C scrollView has object of NSURLConnection.
and this functioned to download an image.

( A -> pushViewController -> B (has C) -> (C process NSURLConnection after initiation))

---

If I dismiss the C scrollView during downloading an image,
occur an Error !! (after finishing download)
Because when B scrollViewController is dismissed, object of C is released.
So, after connection 'didFinished', not search C delegate (after calling didFinished, process B object method.)

here is a part of C's code.

```
 
- (void)downloadScreenshotWithURLString:(NSString *)aURLString {

 AsyncImageViewDownload* download;   // AsyncImageViewDownload has NSURLConnection

 download = [[AsyncImageViewDownload alloc] initWithURL:aURLString delegate:self selector:@selector(urlDownload:data:error:)];
 [[self operationQueue] addOperation:download];
 [download release]; 

}

// After download.
- (void)urlDownload:(AsyncImageView *)aDownload data:(NSData *)data error:(NSError *)error  {  
    if (data)  
    {  
        // add ImageData to the front view.
 [self displayScreenshot:data];
    }  
    else  
    {  
        NSLog(@"download error: %@", error);  
    }  
}
```

and dealloc method of B is here.

```
- (void)dealloc {
        [C release];
 C = nil;
        [super dealloc];
}
```

How can't I occur an Error??
Please help me...

Answer (score 0):

I knew it. So simple.

connection cancel is correct answer.

I think I'm beginner ㅠ,.ㅠ;;